# How to set background image in center of the panel in Basic4Android

Tags: panel, basic4android

I want set the background image for a panel in the center of it. But how  can I set the image in center of panel?

I wrote this code:

```
Dim panel21 As Panel
panel21.Initialize("panel21")
ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(panel21, 0, 138%y, 100%x, 12%y)
panel21.SetBackgroundImage(LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets, "home.png"))
```

But I don't want to set background for it in designer mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center screen that panel, you can add in to Activity!

You can add this picture center of the screen like this;

```
Dim p as Panel
p.initialize("p")
p.SetBackgroundImage(LoadBitmap(dir,fileName))

Dim W As Int = 400dip 'This is picture width
Dim H As Int = 300dip ' and height

Activity.AddView(p, (100%x - W)/2, (100%y - H)/2 , W, H)
```

if you sure to add scrollview, you must add scrollview to activiy first, and replace 100%x with scrollview.width and 100%y with scrollview.height.